# Реализация интерфейса php codeigniter interface

Tags: php, ооп, mvc, codeigniter, интерфейс

При создании интерфейса выходит вот такая ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю:
1) Использую codeigniter 3 версии
2) И по этому принципу [ccылка от куда я капал](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-use-interface-in-Codeigniter-a-framework-for-PHP) пытаюсь реализовать interface

как видите не может найти MY_LOADER. Не могу понять почему так?

Или есть ли  другие способы создания и использования interface именно в codeigniter?

Comment: весьма странно, получается, что CI догадался, что вам нужен MY_Loader, но не нашел его. Первое, что приходит в голову, что у вас файл есть, а класс не произошел. Покажите текст MY_loader.php

Comment: @splash58  https://ibb.co/wBGKPrp по этой ссылке разместил скриншот